# vlc streaming with v4l2. how can i choose the input channel ? (svideo)

Tags: video, streaming, vlc-media-player, input

I have a saa7134 video broadcast decoder that is working well, i can see picture using tvtime or xawtv. now i want to be able to broadcast using vlc, the problem is that i can't find where to choose in vlc the input channel. i want to choose svideo. any ideas ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's under Advanced Options on mine. I can't remember if it's labeled "input" or "channel" but possible values for my card are 0 (tuner), 1 (s-video), 2 (composite). I'll check the details when I get home today.

This is under Ubuntu 9.10 running VLC 1.03 with a Hauppauge PVR-250.

Comment: thanks!!! i had input option there, by using v4l-info i could see that S-Video is on channel 3 and when i chose it, it worked.

Answer (score 4):

Use `v4l2-ctl` in the `ivtv-utils` package.

Display inputs:
`v4l2-ctl -n`

Query currently selected input:
`v4l2-ctl -I`

Select input $N:
`v4l2-ctl -i $N`